# Certificate Mapping in IIS

Tags: tls, authentication, certificates

When pasting the certificate blob in the configuration editor in IIS 7.5 for one on one authentication, is this the server certificate or the client certificate?

Answer (score 1):

What happens in IIS under the name of "certificate mapping" is *always* about the client certificate. In SSL (HTTPS), the server may request a certificate from the client, in which case the client sends his certificate and proves his control of the corresponding private key (this is handled in the SSL protocol; the client computes a signature on a challenge from the server). The server *validates* the client certificate (it verifies all the signatures on the chain, from a root CA down to the client certificate itself), and then *maps* that certificate on a client identity; "certificate mapping" is about that last step.

More generically, when an entity owns a certificate, then it never really needs to validate it. The server's certificate is meant for the clients, not for the server itself. From the server point of view, the server's certificate is just some opaque blob which should be sent to the clients, and the clients look at its contents.

**Your certificate is for the other people.**